# Is it a good idea to have our CI server automatically run rails migrations and commit schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, commit, rails-migrations, schema.rb

At my company, we're seeing intermittent issues with fields appearing/disappearing, errant tables appearing, and conflicts in our `schema.rb` file. These problems have been happening consistently and waste our time.

I'm having a hard time convincing my co-worker that our migration/`schema.rb` problems can be fixed simply by using a standard workflow.

First, the facts:

- We have `schema.rb` under source control
- We know that `schema.rb` should be the definitive source of truth for our database
- We use SqlServer in production/QA and Postgresql for development/testing
- This means we actually have two `schema.rb` files: one for SqlServer and one for Postgresql.
- Our current `schema.rb` files are out of sync with our production database because we've allowed developers to pollute it with local changes.

I believe that (most of) our migration/`schema.rb` problems will be solved by following this simple rule:

> Before you run a migration, always load your schema into a newly created database:
>
> `rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate`
>
> Then, review your changes carefully to be confident that only the changes from your migration(s) are committed to schema.rb

My co-worker believes it would be better to not allow developers to change `schema.rb`, but instead have a task on our Jenkins server that would run migrations and automatically commit changes to `schema.rb`. He says that we should remove the human element from our process and automate the work, and this will not allow problems to happen in the future.

While I believe in automating away work, I don't believe this is the best solution, since it merely targets a symptom and not the cause. Automating git commits makes me nervous because so many things can go wrong. More importantly, separating migrations and their corresponding `schema.rb` changes seems like a *really bad idea* to me. We shouldn't continue to allow our developers to be ignorant of the negative impact of polluting `schema.rb`. We should instead teach them a better workflow that will avoid polluting `schema.rb`, and give them the knowledge to debug problems when they do occur in the future.

Can people please weigh in and recommend which of our solutions is better? Or a better solution we haven't thought of yet?

Comment: Your developers should all be working on feature branches, and committing any changes there, including changes to schema.rb and the migrations that introduce those changes. I can't see how this is introducing a problem. When the branch passes, it gets merged, including its changes to schema.rb and its migrations. If things are appearing and disappearing in schema.rb, you need to coach your team on how to resolve conflicts to that file.

Comment: You should also be code-reviewing branches before they're merged, and changes to schema.rb that don't come from a migration are easy to spot and call out.